# How to add the label to the polygon in the mapbox

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am going to add the label on the polygon in the mapbox, btw I can't find out the solution how to add the label.

I found the way to add the label to the points.

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "points",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [-77.03238901390978, 38.913188059745586]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": "Mapbox DC",
                    "icon": "monument"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [-122.414, 37.776]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": "Mapbox SF",
                    "icon": "harbor"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "layout": {
        "icon-image": "{icon}-15",
        "text-field": "{title}",
        "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
        "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
        "text-anchor": "top"
    }
});
```

So I tried to add the label to the polygon in the mapbox using above solution but failed.

Please help me!

Comment: It looks ok. What goes wrong? Have you checked the console for errors? A possible cause is that you haven't loaded any glyphs for your map.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely want to convert your Polygons into Points and use that for your labels source.

You can do this directly in your app with  https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel or before hand with https://github.com/andrewharvey/geojson-polygon-labels

Comment: Thanks for your help